# Zend Mail keeps giving me a Socket Error

Tags: zend-framework, zend-mail

I'm having trouble with sending email using the zend framework. I keep getting a "Could not open socket" error.

I don't know whats wrong here - it used to work on my other host. Ever since I shifted it to another host I can't send emails. I've set up the configuration values to match the new email server.

Heres my code:

```
$config = array('auth' => _config('mail', 'auth'),
        'username' => _config('mail', 'email'),
        'password' => _config('mail', 'password'));

$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp(_config('mail', 'smtp'), $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->setDefaultTransport($tr);

$mail->setFrom(_config('mail','email'), _config('mail','name'));
$mail->addTo($account_email);

$mail->setSubject($mailTitle);
$mail->setBodyText($mailContent);
$mail->send($tr);
```

EDIt ===

Well the code posted above is my actual code - I don't know whats wrong with it as it used to work on another host.

The following is the exact error I'm getting

```
Could not open socketstring(1237) "#0 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(167): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_connect('tcp://mail.indi...') 
#1 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(199): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->connect() 
#2 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail() 
#3 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail)) 
#4 /home/india/public_html/demo/application/controllers/AccountController.php(2153): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp)) 
#5 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): AccountController->forgetPasswordAction() 
#6 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('forgetPasswordA...') 
#7 /home/india/public_html/demo/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#8 /home/india/public_html/demo/application/bootstrap.php(26): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() #9 /home/india/public_html/demo/html/index.php(4): Bootstrap::run() #10 {main}"
```

Answer (score 1):

marhaba Ali! , 
digging the code of Zend mail shows http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php

```
 protected function _connect($remote)
    {
        $errorNum = 0;
        $errorStr = '';

        // open connection
        $this->_socket = @stream_socket_client($remote, $errorNum, $errorStr, self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);

        if ($this->_socket === false) {
            if ($errorNum == 0) {
                $errorStr = 'Could not open socket';
            }
            /**
             * @see Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception
             */
            require_once 'Zend/Mail/Protocol/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception($errorStr);
        }

        if (($result = $this->_setStreamTimeout(self::TIMEOUT_CONNECTION)) === false) {
            /**
             * @see Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception
             */
            require_once 'Zend/Mail/Protocol/Exception.php';
            throw new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception('Could not set stream timeout');
        }

        return $result;
    }
```

and usually the error number 0 because of

```
  if ($errorNum == 0) {
                    $errorStr = 'Could not open socket';
               }
```

from : http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php

> On failure the errno and errstr
>   arguments will be populated with the
>   actual system level error that
>   occurred in the system-level connect()
>   call. If the value returned in errno
>   is 0 and the function returned FALSE,
>   it is an indication that the error
>   occurred before the connect() call.
>   This is most likely due to a problem
>   initializing the socket. Note that the
>   errno and errstr arguments will always
>   be passed by reference.

I guess its some firewall blocking the connection to be sent out , 
system-level or network-level error

If you update your answer with more detailed info  , i would be happy to help